# Nodejs mongoose complex query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just can't get my head around this. I'm trying to get a query result in mongoose. I have a database of journeys which include a route of stops. I want to get all journeys that visit a target station (bonus: and use a certain platform).

Here is what the schemata look like:

```
var StopSchema = new Schema({
  arrival: String,
  departure: String,
  platform: String,
  station: String,
});

var JourneySchema = new Schema({
  trainNumber: String,
  destination: String,
  route: [StopSchema]
});
```

exampleData:

```
{
  trainNumber: '1',
  destination: 'Z',
  route: [
  { arrival: "11:23", departure: "11:25", platform: "3", station: "A"},
  { arrival: "11:33", departure: "11:35", platform: "3", station: "B"},
  { arrival: "11:43", departure: "11:45", platform: "3", station: "Z"}
  ]
},
{
  trainNumber: '2',
  destination: 'Z',
  route: [
  { arrival: "12:23", departure: "12:25", platform: "3", station: "A"},
  { arrival: "12:33", departure: "12:35", platform: "3", station: "B"},
  { arrival: "12:43", departure: "12:45", platform: "3", station: "Z"}
  ]
},
{
  trainNumber: '3',
  destination: 'F',
  route: [
  { arrival: "12:23", departure: "12:25", platform: "3", station: "D"},
  { arrival: "12:33", departure: "12:35", platform: "3", station: "E"},
  { arrival: "12:43", departure: "12:45", platform: "3", station: "Z"}
  ] 
}
```

Request: get all journeys visiting "B" (on platform 3), list the route and promote the target station data

desiredResult:

```
[
{
  trainNumber: '1',
  destination: 'Z',
  route:  [
  { arrival: "11:23", departure: "11:25", platform: "3", station: "A"},
  { arrival: "11:33", departure: "11:35", platform: "3", station: "B"},
  { arrival: "11:43", departure: "11:45", platform: "3", station: "Z"}
  ],
  targetStation: {  arrival: "11:33", departure: "11:35", platform: "3", station: "B"}
},
{
  trainNumber: '2',
  destination: 'Z',
  route: [
  { arrival: "12:23", departure: "12:25", platform: "3", station: "A"},
  { arrival: "12:33", departure: "12:35", platform: "3", station: "B"},
  { arrival: "12:43", departure: "12:45", platform: "3", station: "Z"}
  ],
  targetStation: {  arrival: "12:33", departure: "12:35", platform: "3", station: "B"}
}
]
```

I just don't know what evil combination of elemmatch/ aggregate/ virtual/ query I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Since MongoDB doesn't support joins you can't do this in a single query with your desired schema. You will need at least two queries: one to fetch the ID of the target stop and then a second to fetch the journeys that has that stop. Something like (assuming models `Stop` and `Journey`):

```
Stop.findOne({station: 'B', platform: '3'}).exec().then(function(stop) {
  if (stop === null) { throw new Error('No stop matches request');
  return Journey.find({route: {_id: stop.id}}).populate('route').exec();
}).then(function(journeys) {
  if (journeys === null || journeys.length === 0) { throw new Error('No journeys include requested stop'); }

  // `journeys` should be an array matching your desired output
  //  you can add the extra property here or in the journeys query if you wish
}).then(null, function (err) {
  // Handle errors
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to do it in multiple steps. But starting with a single stop is strange, since I need to get all journeys at that station. I will play around with the pieces from your answer, thanks.

Comment: Your example showed a single target stop hence the sample code provided. The second query grabs all journeys that include that stop. That said, it's trivial to make it query for multiple stops if that's what you want.